# How to decrypt information from package versions?

Tags: package-management

What these numbers mean? Take look at concrete example from aptitude:

```
chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra could be upgraded to version                     
31.0.1650.63-0ubuntu0.13.10.1~20131204.1, but it is being held at version     
30.0.1599.114-0ubuntu0.13.10.2.
```

Why so many numbers? How can I tell whether I should upgrade or not? The last thing I want is to prevent upgrades in future because newer software might require older packages. I don't recall holding this package and others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically:

```
31.0.1650.63-0ubuntu0.13.10.1~20131204.1
|----------| | |----|
  Upstream   |    |
  version    |    |
          Debian  |
          version |
               Ubuntu
               Versioning
```

That cover the basic, but what about the next numbers?

- The `13.10` is the version of Ubuntu, since the packages of different versions of Ubuntu are compiled quite differently and will collide if they have the same name in the mirror. These packages are exclusive to that version of Ubuntu.
- `.1` means that is the first version for that package.
- `~20131204` Is the date the package was built.
- The second `.1` is in case the package is built twice the same day.

Now, why in the world has a complicated version number? Because Chrome/ium is compiled separately but must have the same versions on all releases of Ubuntu, and to differentiate them all the package managers use these kinds of overly complex versions number.

> I don't recall holding this package and others as well.

In this case is "held" has another meaning. It's being held because apt will break dependencies if it gets upgraded. This cases are normally solved upgrading both packages or using an advance resolver like `aptitude`.